# Get coordinates of image after warpPerspective

Tags: python, opencv

I apply cv2.warpPerspective to imageA

```
result = cv2.warpPerspective(imageA, Ht.dot(H), (xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin))
```

and that work works correctly, but i need coordinates of new image like this
[image]

Maybe anybody knows how to calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

old_points=[[[   3.27589822,  -24.28251266]],[[   8.85595226,  270.21176147]], [[ 408.69842529,  258.427948  ]],[[ 398.14550781,  -36.64953613]]]

new_points = cv2.perspectiveTransform(old_points, H)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a point of confusion this question helped me solve, the points need to be in 1 more level of array nesting than I was expecting.

```
points = [ [x1,y1] , [x2,y2] , [x3,y3] , [x4,y4] ]
transformedPoints = cv2.perspectiveTransform(np.array([points]), H)[0]
```

Here I've put the points inside a 1 element long array, then took the first element [0] as output.